# Add remove links don't work in complex nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am trying to create a complex form from the nested models rails cast. Projects and Tasks are the two forms I have. Tasks belongs to projects. Projects have many tasks.

My form is created successfully and the relationship between the two models appears correct. I can destroy projects and it will remove tasks associated with the project. My issue occurs when I try to use javascript to remove and add tasks to projects. The links get created successfully, the form loads in the browser successfully, I can submit the form without a problem, however when I click on the "remove" or "add" links nothing happens.

Nothing in the logs, no error messages in the browser. here is my application.js and my application_helper.js and the form.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require_tree .
function remove_fields(link) {
    $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
    $(link).up(".fields").hide();
}
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
    $(link).up().insert({
        before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
    });
}
```

application_helper.js

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
        f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
    end

    def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
        new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
        fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
            render(association.to_s.singularize, :f => builder)
        end
        #link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
        link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}'')")
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
  <p>
     <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
     <%= f.text_field :name %> <br />
     <%= f.label :description, "Description" %>
     <%= f.text_field :description %> <br />
     <%= f.label :project_id, "Project ID" %>
     <%= f.text_field :project_id %> <br />
     <%= f.label :id, "ID" %>
     <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </p>

  <h3> Tasks for Project </h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'task', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Task", f, :tasks %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>

<% end %>
```

_task.html.erb

```
<div class="fields"> 
    <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %></br >
    <%= f.label :description, "description" %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 3 %><br />
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jquery, you should use the `parent()` instead of `up()` which is a prototype function and change the `insert()` to `append()`. So your javascript code would look like:

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").val(1);
  $(link).parent(".fields").hide();
}
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().append(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

But if you don't want to write all these messy stuff by yourself, you can use [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form). It is really good gem for complex forms.

Comment: I'm going to have to abandon this as I have spent too much time on trying to get the syntax correct. Nested_form gem it is! Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you forgot to end your < p > in the link_to_add_fields line

Then, maybe this following lines were not correctly executed by your version of jQuery.

```
$(link).up().insert({
    before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
});
```

To be sure there are not a problem, try to write this line before the line_to_add_field

and change the 3 previous lines to

```
$('#task_attributes').append(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
```

If this doesn't work, update your first message to show the generated code of the "link_to_add_field" rails function.